# Grails domain Named query for a list

Tags: grails, grails-orm, named-query, domain-object

I have a simple Grails application. I have a couple of domains such as following. The scenario is Person has many Telephone (But person class does not have a list of telephone as a variable : Lazy Single-Ended Associations).

```
class Person implements Serializable {
    ....
}

class Telephone implements Serializable{
    String number
    static belongsTo = [person : Person]
    static mapping = {
        .....
        person lazy: false
    }
}
```

Now I have a requirement where I have to search the person by telephone numbers. I have a list of string telephone numbers. I need to get all the persons whom have at least one of that telephone number. I need to write namedQueries, but I'm quite new to this area. Is it possible to write named queries for this? Or do I need a mapping defined in Person class as

```
set telephone
static hasMany = [
        telephone: Telephone
]
```

And how would the namedQueries should be defined to suit my requirement

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe for it to be able to see telephone from person you are correct that a

```
set telephone
static hasMany = [
        telephone: Telephone
]
```

needs to be defined but once defined you can then just do:

```
 static namedQueries = {
       withSameTelephone {telephoneNumber -> 
             telephone{ eq 'number' telephoneNumber }
       }
   }
```

and use it like:

```
Person.withSameTelephone('091511234512').list()
```

I think you need to pass a list so

```
 static namedQueries = {
       withSameTelephoneInList {telephoneNumberList -> 
             telephone{ 'in'( 'number' telephoneNumber) }
       }
   }
```

so you could do:

```
Person.withSameTelephoneInList(['091511234512','091511234513','091511234514']).list()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd stick with single-ended o2m, and put a named query like:

```
class Telephone {

  ...

  static namedQueries = {
    byPerson{ Person p ->
      eq 'person', p
    }          
  }
}
```

and call it like:

```
Person p = Person.get 1111
def telephones = Telephone.byPerson p
```

On the other hand you can use a simple `findAllBy*` query:

```
Person p = Person.get 1111
def telephones = Telephone.findAllByPerson p
```